Why is LaTex not printing my glossary
%%
%% ========== TITLE INFORMATION ==========
%%
%% Thesis type: DA ... diploma thesis, DISS ... PhD thesis
\newcommand{\thesistype}{DA} 
%%
%% language of your thesis: de-AT ... German, en-US or en-UK ... English
\newcommand{\thesislanguage}{de-AT}
%% thesistitle is the title in the language of the thesis
%% if thesislanguage is English (en-US or en-UK), the title has to be in English
%% if thesislanguage is German (de-AT), the title has to be in German
\newcommand{\thesistitle}{Bewertung einer Photovoltaikanlage im Mittelspannungsnetz}
%% thesistitletranslated is the title either in english or german
%% if thesislanguage is English, the translated title has to be in German
%% if thesislanguage is German, the translated title has to be in English
\newcommand{\thesistitletranslated}{Evaluation of a photovoltaic system in the medium-voltage grid}
%%
%
\documentclass[11pt,twoside=true]{scrreprt}
%\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{scrreprt}
%
%% consider that the input encoding of all should be utf8 
%% if you use the follwing setting, otherwise change it
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{TUWBUIDADISS}
%% this style includes already some packages which have been very useful 
%% in the last diploma or doctoral theses
%%
%% fontenc[T1], lmodern, microtype, babel[englisch,ngerman], graphicx, 
%% geometry with all margins or areaset (choose what you like)
%% mathtools, amssymb, xfrac, siunitx, booktabs,
%% url, xcolor[table], textcomp, marvosym, pifonts, pdfpages, ragged2e, 
%% tabularx, longtable, threeparttable, csquotes, eurosym, enumitem, 
%% multirow, setspace, listings, scrlayer-scrpage with header/footline
%% pdfx (including hyperref)

\raggedbottom 
%% prevents the expansion of the text till the end of the page (if you like)
%\setcapindent{0em} %% influences captions layout
%%
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,backend=biber,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{%
  giveninits=true,maxbibnames=99}%
\DefineBibliographyStrings{ngerman}{andothers={et\;al\adddot},
urlseen = {Zugriff am}}
\addbibresource{Literatur.bib}


%% ===== additional packages to the ones already loaded ==============
\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{formulas}

\usepackage{acro}
\input{Acronyms}


%% ===== additional settings =============
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,},
range-phrase = --,
group-separator = {~},
per-mode = symbol, 
list-final-separator={ und }}

\graphicspath{{Bilder/}}

%% examples for useful shortcuts in German
\newcommand{\zB}{\mbox{z.\,B.}\xspace}
\newcommand{\Name}[1]{\textsc{#1}}


% activate for double space between the lines (correction mode) 
%\doublespacing

\begin{document}       %% start of the document
\maketitle             %% places the title with above information

\cleardoublepage
\selectlanguage{ngerman}  %% for german abstract
\include{00-Kurzfassung}      %% german abstract (about 1 page)

\cleardoublepage
\selectlanguage{english}    %% for english abstract
\include{00-abstract}         %% english abstract (about 1 page)

%\cleardoublepage
\selectlanguage{ngerman} 
\pagestyle{scrheadings} 

\tableofcontents

%% now include all chapter files -- use the include-command (takes care
%% that all not yet output floats are output before the new file)
%%
\glsaddall
\printglossary[title={Formelzeichen}]
\printacronyms[name=Abkürzungen]

\include{Einleitung/Aufgabenstellung}
\include{Einleitung/01-Einleitung}
\include{Hauptteil/Übersicht}
\include{Hauptteil/Berechnungen_PF}
\include{Hauptteil/Gesamtbewertung}
\include{Einleitung/beispiele1}
\include{Einleitung/beispiele2}
%etc.

%% insert bibliography, adds chapter heading with chapter number
\printbibliography ```

EDIT: output.glg
*** Unable to execute: '"makeindex"  -s "output.ist" -t "/compile/output.glg" -o "/compile/output.gls" "/compile/output.glo"' ***

Failed with error code 1.

Status report:

Index style file output.ist not found.
Usage: makeindex [-ilqrcgLT] [-s sty] [-o ind] [-t log] [-p num] [idx0 idx1 ...]

makeindex didn't create a transcript.
Check that makeindex has been installed and
is on your system's PATH.
Your PATH environment variable is set to: 
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/texlive/2023/bin/x86_64-linux/
Try manually running:
"makeindex"  -s "output.ist" -t "/compile/output.glg" -o "/compile/output.gls" "/compile/output.glo"


makeglossaries diagnostic messages:
Style file not found. (Have you used \noist by mistake?)


How are you compiling? Have you run makeglossaries (see this answer and this answer)? Are there any errors in the log or glg files?

All those \newcommands and comments are unrelated to your problem and make it hard to see what you're doing.  And the \includes make it impossible to see what you're doing.  If DaiBowen's suggestions don't help (my guess is they will), please create a minimal working example (MWE) that you think should produce a glossary but doesn't.

Im using Overleaf, i barely know anything about LaTex, i tried this glossary setup on a completely new file and it worked there with the same setup

Overleaf should be running makeglossaries for you so that's OK, hit "Recompile from scratch" just in case there's something in an auxiliary file playing up. Assuming that doesn't resolve it, there's probably an error,  try commenting out the \includes and recompiling from scratch to see if that localises it, then download the .log, .glg and .blg files generated and go through them carefully looking for any errors.

I found this in the raw logs: Package glossaries Info: Writing glossary file output.glo on input line 113.
(./Formelzeichen.tex) (/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/acro/acro.sty
Package: acro 2022/04/01 v3.8 typeset acronyms and other abbreviations (CN)   I use acro package for seperate abreviations, do they interfere which eachother ?

I suggest to take smaller bites of this elephant. Put your document aside for the moment and try a very simple one with a glossary. Use books on Latex or answers to glossary questions (click on that tag) to come up with a very simple working example. Once you know how it works, return to your document AND apply the 50:50 strategy to narrow down your trouble. See this 50:50 example https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/717341/245790

Is your main tex file in the root of the project or a subfolder? Could be this issue

I have a folder where everything, including the main.tex is located, so your suggesting removing that main folder completely ?

The main.tex needs to be in the project root for Overleaf's compilation rules to run makeglossaries successfully.  There's no need for everything to be in a folder rather than the project root so moving it all out saves adjusting the paths in your main.tex.

Yep, that fixed it, thank you man

Solved:
\makenoidxglossaries
\printnoidxglossary

This just circumvents the need to run makeglossaries at the expense of making the latex compilation slower, ordinarily running makeglossaries should be simple.
